Query data with specific key:value from multiple windows of data into one JSON record
I am trying to manipulate the data from an API call. What I want to do is call the data over the past 30 days but only return the json results of data containing a certain key:value.

Query raw API data by 1800 secs window
Get data from past 30 days
Search this data for records containing a certain key:value
Get the above filtered data in JSON file and convert into CSV.

These are the following limits and parameters for each call:
Authorization is Oauth2.
params = {
                'direction': 'LEFT',  # LEFT or RIGHT
                'window': '1800',  # in seconds, queries the data in the past 1800 seconds of basetime
                'basetime': '2024-04-10T07:00:00.000000'  # in yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS:ssssss
            }

Limits:
Maximum payload is 1800 records. # Therefore recommended to query by 1800secs window to avoid missing data.
Tried the below code but it just keeps querying the data at window = 1800 at the same basetime. Not sure how I can query it by basetime instead by changing the basetime backwards every 30min.
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import datetime


def get_data_past30days():
    # OAuth2 credentials
    client_key = 'd12345'
    client_secret = '5678901'
    token_url = 'https://gettoken.com'

    # API endpoint
    api_url = 'https://getdata.com'

    # Create OAuth2 session
    client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_key)
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
    token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, client_id=client_key, client_secret=client_secret)

    # Prepare headers and body
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token'],
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  
    }

    # get_past30days
    basetime = "2024-04-10T07:00:00.000000"
    basetime_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(basetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f') #to convert basetime to int for past_30_days
    past_30_days = (basetime_datetime - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000')


    while basetime >= past_30_days:
        for seconds in basetime:
            seconds = +1800
            basetime = (basetime_datetime - datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000')

            params = {
                'direction': 'LEFT',  # LEFT or RIGHT
                'window': '1800',  # in seconds, queries the data in the past 1800 seconds of basetime
                'basetime': '2024-04-10T07:00:00.000000'  # in yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS:ssssss
            }

            # Make API call
            response = requests.get(url=api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
            data = response.json()

            seconds = +1800
            basetime = (basetime_datetime - datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000')

            # Check response
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(data)
            else:
                print("API call failed with status code:", response.status_code)
                print("Response:", response.text)
    else:
        print("Data not available past 30 days")

get_data_past30days()

